# How to Capture Repeating Groups at end of Asymmetrical Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I know there are lots of existing questions on capturing groups and I've read about a dozen but I can't seem to get any to solve the problem I'm having. I have a string of this form:
`{{First String/Second String|{Thing1}|{Thing2}|{Thing3}|{Thing4}|}}`
Where the first part is fixed but for the {Thingx} portion there can be anywhere from 0 to n. I would like to end up with an array of
Full Match
First String
Second String
Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
Thing4

I'm using regex101.com to test. I have an [initial regex](https://regex101.com/r/otNP1t/2)
`/{{(.+?)\/(.+?)\|({.+?}\|)}}/`
that can capture all the `{Thingx}` piece as a single group. Then I can use a [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/w0zYf2/1)
 `/{(.*?)}\|/`
to break them up. Is if there is a single regex that can do both steps?

Comment: `{Thingx} portion there can be anywhere from 0 to n` Then this can't bee done with a single regex. The `Thingx` have to all be captured within a single group. After the match, that group can be further subdivided with another regex, where the two arrays can be joined. So, _NO_ can't be done in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about relying on multiple matches instead of groups. You could use the Boolean `OR` `|` to achieve that in regex in one line. The regex would be

```
{{([^\/]*)|\/(.*?)\||{(.*?)}
```

A complete example could be something like this

```js
var str = '{{First String/Second String|{Thing1}|{Thing2}|{Thing3}|{Thing4}|}}';
var myRegexp = /{{([^\/]*)|\/(.*?)\||{(.*?)}/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  if (typeof match[1] != 'undefined') console.log(match[1])
  if (typeof match[2] != 'undefined') console.log(match[2])
  if (typeof match[3] != 'undefined') console.log(match[3])
  console.log("---------------------------");
  match = myRegexp.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I'll have to get more familiar with the concept of multiple matches. This will make a nice clean solution.